# CiviCRM URL issue: CiviCRM theme is not loading after CiviCRM update to 5.26.1 version

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home, evaluating-civicrm, civicrm.settings.php, drupal-8

After upgrading the CiviCRM to the latest version 5.26.1, the CiviCRM theme is not loading.

I have checked on the Browser Console and I saw a CSS and JS file errors. Some of the errors are given below -

> The resource from
> “`{{domain-name}}//srv/bindings/28583aa6b…vicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>
> The resource from
> “`{{domain-name}}//srv/bindings/28583aa6b…wer_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css`”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>
> The resource from
> “`{{domain-name}}//srv/bindings/28583aa6b…l/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`”
> was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
>
> Loading failed for the with source
> “`{{domain-name}}//srv/bindings/28583aa6b…l/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`”.

How can I fix this issue? Please advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you add below lines in your civicrm.settings.php?

```
global $civicrm_paths;
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['url'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . '/sites/all/modules/civicrm';
```

Comment: Okay, I will check, If this line is not there, I will add it and let you know.

Comment: Thank You! It's worked for me. The theme is loading properly.