# Paths are inconsistent

Tags: configuration

We are having an issue where the /bower_components and /packages paths are being rendered differently than other paths. This is causing the JQuery and other components to not load correctly. I've tried setting this in civicrm.settings.php, but can not see to get them to use the correct URL

CiviCRM 5.25.0, Drupal 7.72, Panheon is the host (thus the path weirdness)

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://carolinaclimbers.org//srv/bindings/e138c004c7534c17a7b6a73b59bc743dsites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://carolinaclimbers.org/sites/default/files/css/css_QSUBb92PTdLEfkMP9h64X2An1s-ea4NW9lWznW1IB3U.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://carolinaclimbers.org/sites/default/files/css/css_k0Qak2KC5ckGFoWNds-UCkJ19u5TyvmyprcB27dAxHw.css" media="all" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://carolinaclimbers.org/sites/default/files/css/css_KLevn940KsaVS6iNiCt9sY13XTqU54F_5IOxYTblXpA.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://carolinaclimbers.org/sites/default/files/js/js_h8Od-FAGkhR_7A30HaaMaTrO_5Hale-5uw8QHV7ogq0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://carolinaclimbers.org//srv/bindings/e138c004c7534c17a7b6a73b59bc743dsites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://carolinaclimbers.org//srv/bindings/e138c004c7534c17a7b6a73b59bc743dsites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://carolinaclimbers.org//srv/bindings/e138c004c7534c17a7b6a73b59bc743dsites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/lodash-compat/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://carolinaclimbers.org//srv/bindings/e138c004c7534c17a7b6a73b59bc743dsites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

the l-10n-js script has these lines: 

CRM.config.resourceBase = "https:\/\/carolinaclimbers.org\/sites\/all\/modules\/civicrm\/"; CRM.config.packagesBase = "https:\/\/carolinaclimbers.org\/\/srv\/bindings\/e138c004c7534c17a7b6a73b59bc743dsites\/all\/modules\/civicrm\/packages\/"; – Brian Payst 1 min ago     Edit
```

Comment: Is this the same as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35937/civicrm-url-issue-civicrm-theme-is-not-loading-after-civicrm-update-to-5-26-1-v ?

Comment: Looks similar and I saw that error as well, but the suggested fix did not seem to correct it

Comment: I see the edit above. You could try something similar to the other question, i.e. `$civicrm_paths['civicrm.packages']['url'] = CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL . '/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages';`

Comment: I tried that and I did it for bower_components as well, still doesn't fix the issue. The JS and CSS lines related to bower_components and packages continue to load with the incorrect path.

Comment: This ended up being a Pantheon environment variables and path change, I fixed if following the suggestions here, edited for my non-starter kit environment: https://github.com/herbdool/civicrm-starterkit-drops-7/pull/17/commits/1d194772d79e2d3ec186d370c78fcfede784c6dd

Comment: Cool. You're allowed to answer your own question so can post the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being a Pantheon environment variables and path change, I fixed if following the suggestions here, edited for my non-starter kit environment: [github.com/herbdool/civicrm-starterkit-drops-7/pull/17/commits/](https://github.com/herbdool/civicrm-starterkit-drops-7/pull/17/commits/)